# How to make Snakemake run a rule once for all matching outputs, not once for each wildcard match

Tags: python, wildcard, bioinformatics, snakemake

In a Snakemake workflow, for efficiency reasons, I want to run a rule once for the *list* of wildcard matches - rather than once for each match.

What's the idiomatic way of doing this in Snakemake?

This is a minimal starter code that does *not* what I want, as it would call `rule produce_all_csvs` once for each of the required outputs (here 3 times) rather than the desired one time.

```
rule all:
    input:
        "out_1.csv",
        "out_2.csv",
        "out_3.csv",


rule produce_all_csv:
    """
    This rule should be called _once_ for _all_ samples
    Not once per sample
    """
    input:
        "in_{sample}.csv",
    output:
        "out_{sample}.csv",
    shell:
        """
        # Placeholder for a real command
        # that takes a list of input files
        # and produces a list of output file
        """
```

For concreteness, assume the tool has this API:

```bash
tool --inputs input_1.csv,input_2.csv --outputs output_1.csv,output_2.csv
```

*This question is inspired by [how to escape MissingOutputException while running a for loop in a rule in snakemake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75603548/how-to-escape-missingoutputexception-while-running-a-for-loop-in-a-rule-in-snake)*

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
SAMPLES = ['1', '2', '3']

rule all:
    input:
        "out_1.csv",
        "out_2.csv",
        "out_3.csv",


rule produce_all_csv:
    input:
        csv=[f"in_{sample}.csv" for sample in SAMPLES],
    output:
        csv=[f"out_{sample}.csv" for sample in SAMPLES],
    params:
        in_csv=lambda wc, input: ','.join(input.csv),
        out_csv=lambda wc, output: ','.join(output.csv),
    shell:
        r"""
        tool --inputs {params.in_csv} --outputs {params.out_csv}
        """
```

You could probably use the `expand` function instead of the list comprehensions.

Comment: Now that I see your solution I'm not sure whether my minimal example wasn't too simplistic. It gets rid of wildcards altogether. I'll think about it and post as another question if I figure out what the issue is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75603548/how-to-escape-missingoutputexception-while-running-a-for-loop-in-a-rule-in-snake